# count :SQL :DB2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have this table:

| CODE | IDNR | NAME | LIMIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 80 | XXX | 2019-05 |
| 123 | 81 | XXX | 2019-10 |
| 124 | 80 | YYY | 2019-01 |
| 125 | 80 | ZZZ | 2019-05 |
| 125 | 81 | ZZZ | 2019-06 |
| 125 | 80 | ZZZ | 2019-07 |
| 126 | 80 | III | 2019-05 |
| 126 | 80 | III | 2019-09 |
| 126 | 80 | III | 2019-07 |

I want to have a new column (Count-LIMIT ) contain how many LIMIT per code, and another contain YES if the limit are continuous and No if not.
MY RESULT  that I want like:

| CODE | IDNR | NAME | LIMIT | Count-Limit | CON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 80 | XXX | 2019-05 | 2 | NO |
| 123 | 81 | XXX | 2019-10 | 2 | NO |
| 124 | 80 | YYY | 2019-01 | 1 | NO |
| 125 | 80 | ZZZ | 2019-05 | 3 | YES |
| 125 | 81 | ZZZ | 2019-06 | 3 | YES |
| 125 | 80 | ZZZ | 2019-07 | 3 | YES |
| 126 | 80 | III | 2019-05 | 3 | NO |
| 126 | 80 | III | 2019-09 | 3 | NO |
| 126 | 80 | III | 2019-07 | 3 | NO |

THANKS!

Comment: To get what you want, you have to write the SQL query. Want to share what you already have...? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @data_henrik what did you mean ? Sql query ?

Comment: Yes, provide the SQL query you wrote

Comment: SELECT CODE  ,IDNR , NAME,  LIMIT  ,COUNT(LIMIT)OVER (PARTITION BY CODE) AS Count-Limit  For rest i know i should  use Case men how?

Comment: I think you are close to what you want. You just need SELECT DISTINCT

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH T (CODE, IDNR, NAME, LIMIT) AS
(
VALUES
  (123, 80, 'XXX', '2019-05')
, (123, 81, 'XXX', '2019-10')
, (124, 80, 'YYY', '2019-01')
, (125, 80, 'ZZZ', '2019-05')
, (125, 81, 'ZZZ', '2019-06')
, (125, 80, 'ZZZ', '2019-07')
, (126, 80, 'III', '2019-05')
, (126, 80, 'III', '2019-09')
, (126, 80, 'III', '2019-07')

, (128, 80, 'AAA', '2021-01')
, (128, 80, 'AAA', '2021-03')
, (128, 80, 'AAA', '2021-05')
, (128, 80, 'AAA', '2021-07')
, (128, 80, 'AAA', '2021-08')
, (128, 80, 'AAA', '2021-09')
)
SELECT 
  T.*
, COUNT (1) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE) AS COUNT_LIMIT
, CASE
    WHEN TO_DATE (LIMIT || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') IN
      (
        LAG  (TO_DATE (LIMIT || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY LIMIT) + 1 MONTH
      , LEAD (TO_DATE (LIMIT || '-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY LIMIT) - 1 MONTH
      )
    THEN 'YES' 
    ELSE 'NO' 
  END AS CON
FROM T
ORDER BY CODE, LIMIT
```

The result is:

| CODE | IDNR | NAME | LIMIT | COUNT_LIMIT | CON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 80 | XXX | 2019-05 | 2 | NO |
| 123 | 81 | XXX | 2019-10 | 2 | NO |
| 124 | 80 | YYY | 2019-01 | 1 | NO |
| 125 | 80 | ZZZ | 2019-05 | 3 | YES |
| 125 | 81 | ZZZ | 2019-06 | 3 | YES |
| 125 | 80 | ZZZ | 2019-07 | 3 | YES |
| 126 | 80 | III | 2019-05 | 3 | NO |
| 126 | 80 | III | 2019-07 | 3 | NO |
| 126 | 80 | III | 2019-09 | 3 | NO |
| 128 | 80 | AAA | 2021-01 | 6 | NO |
| 128 | 80 | AAA | 2021-03 | 6 | NO |
| 128 | 80 | AAA | 2021-05 | 6 | NO |
| 128 | 80 | AAA | 2021-07 | 6 | YES |
| 128 | 80 | AAA | 2021-08 | 6 | YES |
| 128 | 80 | AAA | 2021-09 | 6 | YES |

Comment: thank you very much . but i have problem with this query  because (if i have limit 2021-07 , 2021-08 2021-09  i  get in the record 2021-07 no and in the 08 ,09 yes . the second problem maybe i have like this

Comment: LIMIT for the same person (128 ex) have  2021-01 ,2021-03 , 2021-05  ,2021-07 ,2021-08, 2021-09  i want to get  yes but result with this no  according to query or ???????

Comment: Look at the updated answer. If it's again not what you need, then edit the question inserting all the values needed for person 128 into both your table and the result.